# Redirect WooCommerce Category to a Page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

My aim is to redirect product category to a page instead of their default category screen
I'm currently using Redirection plugin (https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) for redirections. Now even thougbh I have added a redirect (as seen in the screenshot), upon clicking drinkware, it still redirects me from https://war.shopeffina.com/product-categories/ page to https://war.shopeffina.com/product-category/drinkware/ and not https://war.shopeffina.com/drinkware/.

*Note that I'm displaying categories (drinkware, t-shirts, women) dynamically through a shortcode

What seems to be the issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add your code in order to assist you

Answer (score 4):

Solution was solved!! Didn't require the redirections plugin for this

It turned out I had to add the following to my functions.php

```
function drinkware_template_redirect(){
    if( function_exists( 'is_product_category' ) && is_product_category( 'drinkware' ) ){
        $redirect_page_id = 720; // adjust to ID of page you are redirecting to
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( $redirect_page_id ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'drinkware_template_redirect' );
```

Answer (score 0):

`

```
function custom_category_template_redirect() {
    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        $category = get_queried_object();

        if ( $category->term_id == 263 ) {
            $redirect_page_id = 140; 
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $redirect_page_id ) );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_category_template_redirect' );
```

`

Here is working code for me...